# PHP - Compare 2 values of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question regarding compare two arrays.
I already search in this forum but nothing like what I want to achieve.

```
$stock = array("7", "5", "3");
$request = array("3", "6", "3");
```

What I want to achieve is, if every value in `$stock` is higher than `$request`, then I can execute the order.
But in this case, request value in position 2 is higher than stock value (6 vs 5).

My question is, how is the code in PHP to compare if there is any value in `$request` is higher than every value in `$stock`?
OR
to compare if every value in `$stock` is higher than every value in `$request`?

[Example of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzHuC.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean by matching indexes, or array in total? Would `$stock` be higher in your example, because 7 is higher than 3, 6, 3, or would it be because 7, 5 and 3 are evaluated individually against 3, 6 and 3?

Comment: In this case, 7(stock) will compare with 3(request), 5(stock) with 6(request) and the last 3 (stock) with the last 3 (request).

Comment: And would it be valid if they are equal? And are they **always** of the same length, or can it vary? If it varies, what should happen then?

Comment: Yes, >= would be valid and they will be always have the same length.

Comment: It that it? `function cmp($stock, $request) {return array_reduce(array_keys($stock), function($carry, $key) use ($stock, $request){$carry &= $stock[$key]>=$request[$key]; return $carry;}, true);}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply loop through the arrays and compare the indexes in the respective arrays. Since it's a fixed length, always, there isn't need for any complex checks or handlings. This assumes that the keys are assigned by PHP, so they all start at 0 and always increase by 1.

```
$stock   = array("7", "5", "3");
$request = array("3", "6", "3");
var_dump(validate_order($stock, $request)); // false

$stock   = array("7", "5", "3");
$request = array("3", "4", "3");
var_dump(validate_order($stock, $request)); // true

function validate_order($stock, $request) {
    foreach ($stock as $key=>$value) // Fixed length, loop through
        if ($value < $request[$key])
            return false; // Return false only if the stock is less than the request
    return true; // If all indexes are higher in stock than request, return true
}
```

Since this function returns a boolean, true/false, simply use that in an `if`-statement, like this

```
if (validate_order($stock, $request)) {
    /* Put your code here */
    /* The order is valid */
} else {
    /* Order is not valid */
}
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/jqsvo)

Comment: And how/where can I put something like echo "<a href='#'>some link</a>";
if all indexes are higher in stock than request (return true)?

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkOrder($stock,$request){
    for($i=0; $i < count($stock); $i++){
        if($stock[$i] < $request[$i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```